# Shouldn't $\liminf(x_n)+\liminf(y_n)=\liminf(x_n+y_n)$ always hold true?

Tags: analysis

Sorry for asking a silly question but shouldn't $\liminf(x_n)+\liminf(y_n)=\liminf(x_n+y_n)$ always hold true?

I mean if $x_n$ and $y_n$ are bounded below, then so is $x_n+y_n$ and we know that we have $\inf(A+B)=\inf(A)+\inf(B)$, so taking limit from both sides gives $\liminf(x_n+y_n) = \liminf(x_n)+\liminf(y_n)$ for the case where both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are bounded.

For the case where one of the sequences is unbounded from the below, then $x_n+ y_n$ is unbounded from the below as well. So, in this case we get $-\infty = -\infty$.

However, my book says $\liminf(x_n)+\liminf(y_n) \leq \liminf(x_n+y_n)$. Where am I wrong? Am I wrong in the unbounded case?

Comment: Say $\{x_n\}=\{1,0,1,0,1,0,1,\cdots\}$  and $\{y_n\}=\{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,\cdots\}$

Comment: Thanks for the counter-example. But can you point out the mistake in my argument?

Comment: I don't understand your argument at all.  Try writing it out explicitly using the counterexample I (or @Ian ) provided.

Comment: @lulu: Ian's answer convinced me that I was adding sequences as adding the sets of their values, which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple counterexample: $x_n=(-1)^n$, $y_n=(-1)^{n+1}$. Then $\liminf x_n=\liminf y_n=-1$ but $\liminf x_n+y_n=0$. The point is that if $x_n$ is large at all indices where $y_n$ is small and vice versa then the liminf of the sum will be bigger because you are "canceling out" the indices where $x_n$ and $y_n$ are small.

The problem in your argument is simply that $\inf_{n \geq m} x_n+y_n \neq \inf_{n \geq m} x_n + \inf_{n \geq m} y_n$. Note that you are not adding sets, you are adding where the indices agree. So in particular $x_n+y_n$ never contains $-2$ even though $\{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \} + \{ y_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ does.

Comment: Ah, you are right. The addition operation on sets is clearly different from addition on sequences. It was so silly of me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ be any positive sequence, bounded or unbounded, and consider $x_n = (-1)^n a_n$ and $y_n = -x_n$. Then $x_n+y_n =  0$ for all $n$ but $\liminf x_n + \liminf y_n = \liminf x_n - \limsup x_n \le 0$, and the inequality is often strict, e.g. if $a_n = 1$ it's $-2$.

What is true is that $\liminf x_n + y_n \ge \liminf x_n + \liminf y_n$ even if $\infty$ is involved.